# Populating Dataset from DataAdapter error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to do what the title said but I get this error at runtime:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Top'.

```
string connString = @"server  =.\sqlexpress; Database=BestScores.mdf; trusted_connection=TRUE; AttachDbFileName= D:\Programing\Projects Visual Studio 2008\JigSaw\JigSaw\bin\Debug\BestScores.mdf";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Top", conn);
da.Fill(ds);//Error
```

Comment: Change your table name. Top is a keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Top` is a *[reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* on Transact-SQL. When you want to use it in your sql command, you have to use it with square brackets like `[TOP]`.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [Top]", conn);
```

That's why you are getting

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Top'

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Top to another name, because TOP is a reserved word on SQL. Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: It is a very bad practice to keep using reserved words as fields, but it is up to you. I would change it to something more readable. So adding [] to the "reserved word" just delays another problems... good luck.

Comment: Be carefull when you use "select *". It works with a few lines in a table, but it is dangerous with millions of rows.